# Use Generic Protocol as Interface

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a `UseCase` protocol, using generic protocol. Then I want to create an interface for all implementation, in order to create mocks for tests.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
struct Product {}

protocol UseCase {
    associatedtype ReturnType
    associatedtype Param
    func execute(_ params: Param, completion: ((ReturnType) -> Void))
}


protocol FetchProductsUseCase: UseCase {
    associatedtype ReturnType = [Product]
    associatedtype Param = Void
}


struct FetchProductsUseCaseImpl: FetchProductsUseCase {
    func execute(_ params: Param , completion: ((ReturnType) -> Void)) {
        completion([])
    }
}

//ERROR: Protocol 'FetchProductsUseCase' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
var useCase: FetchProductsUseCase!
```

Can someone help me to fix that?

I've search over SOF, and I found multiple of topics about generics, but none of them are helpful for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So there is no way to "constraint" the FetchProductUse case to only accept one couple of Generics ? ( ie: Void/[Product] ) ?

Yes, but your `FetchProductsUseCase` is not how you do it. Do this instead:

```
struct AnyUseCase<P, R>: UseCase {

    typealias ReturnType = R
    typealias Param = P

    init<U>(useCase: U) where U: UseCase, U.ReturnType == ReturnType, U.Param == Param {
        _execute = useCase.execute
    }

    func execute(_ params: P, completion: ((R) -> Void)) {
        _execute(params, completion)
    }

    let _execute: (P, (R) -> Void) -> Void
}

var useCase: AnyUseCase<Void, [Product]>!
```

Then you can do something like:

```
useCase = AnyUseCase(useCase: FetchProductsUseCaseImpl())
```

I think your next error is going to be that `completion` is not escaping. It probably needs to be.